# Python prometheus_client, how to get counter from the registry?

Tags: python, prometheus

How can I obtain a Counter object from the registry?
In the example below, I am currently using the private argument to achieve this.
Perhaps someone knows a more elegant way to accomplish this using only public methods?

```py
from prometheus_client import CollectorRegistry, Counter, write_to_textfile

registry = CollectorRegistry()

name = "NAME"
counter = Counter(name, "DOCUMENTATION", registry=registry)
counter.inc(2)

# get a Counter object from the registry and increment value to 5
counter = registry._names_to_collectors.get(name)
if isinstance(counter, Counter):
    counter.inc(3)

write_to_textfile("counters.prom", registry)
# # HELP NAME_total DOCUMENTATION
# # TYPE NAME_total counter
# NAME_total 5.0
# # HELP NAME_created DOCUMENTATION
# # TYPE NAME_created gauge
# NAME_created 1.7029690363513136e+09
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Based on code I'd guess that maybe methods `restricted_registry` and `collect` can replace usage of `_names_to_collectors`, but it's hard to tell exactly, without knowing what code supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

## The same problem I had

In my personal project, I have the same problem and I adopted this solution.

In `CollectorRegistry`, the class where you store your metrics, there's no method to get `Collector` object (`Collector` is the parent class of any metric like `Counter`, `Gauge`, `Histogram`, etc.).

The `restricted_registry` method creates a subset (a restricted registry) where you have the `Metrics` that have that name and labels.
But "it's experimental", so be careful. It doesn't solve my (our) problem. Because if a metric has a label, you also have to specify its value, and sometimes you can't know it (for example, if you're counting how many https requests you've made):

```
def restricted_registry(self, names: Iterable[str]) -> "RestrictedRegistry":
    """Returns object that only collects some metrics.

    Returns an object which upon collect() will return
    only samples with the given names.

    Intended usage is:
        generate_latest(REGISTRY.restricted_registry(['a_timeseries']))

    Experimental."""
    names = set(names)
    return RestrictedRegistry(names, self)
```

So if you're coding a project, and not its tests, don't use it.

---

## My solutions adopted

### First solution (fast implementation)

The **first** is to store all your metrics inside a custom class (eg `PrometheusMetrics`) where you have a dictionary with all `Metrics` object, for example (return objects are custom for my case, if you want to use a parent class, writes `Collector`):

```
def register_new_metrics(self, metrics: list[Counter | Gauge | Histogram | Summary | Enum]):
    for metric in metrics:
        for metric_obj in metric.describe():
            # Register the new metric inside the registry
            self.get_registry().register(metric)
            # Add it to the dict
            self._metric[metric_obj.name] = metric
```

And you can invoke it in this way:

```
self.register_new_metrics([
            Counter(f'name', "documentation", ['label1','label2']),
            Histogram(f'name2', "documentation", ['label1', 'label2', 'label3'])
])
```

This way you can have a simple `get('metric_name')` method that returns a requested metric object. This solution doesn't cause any problems if you only create metrics once at the same time as you create a `CollectorRegistry` (e.g.).

But if you want to create metrics at runtime, don't use this solution. Because Prometheus uses a `threading.Lock` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/threading.html#threading.Lock)) inside the `CollectorRegistry` class and uses it for a lot of operations.

### Second solution (more logical than the first)

The **second**, in my opinion, is another more logical solution. You can create a subclass of `CollectorRegistry` and create your own method where you get metrics using the protected field `self._names_to_collectors` and lock the thread with `self._lock`.
After that you can register your own subclass using "Custom Collectors" way ([doc](https://prometheus.github.io/client_python/collector/custom/)):

```
from prometheus_client import REGISTRY

REGISTRY.register(CustomRegistry())

class CustomRegistry(CollectorRegistry):
    # ...
    def get_metric(metric: str) -> Collector:
        with self._lock:
            self._names_to_collectors.get(metric)
    # ...
```

**If anyone has a better solution, please write! I am also interested in this topic.**